# I have two tables Table1 and Table2 :I want to swap name column value From Table1 to Table2 and Table2 to Table1

Tags: sql-server

[Below are two tables Table1 and Table2][1]

Table1:Column names id,name 
Table2:Column names id,name

After the swap ,the name column data of Table1 will reflect in Table2 and name of Table2 will reflect in Table1.

I tried to resolve the issue using below query:

```
update table1 t set t.name=replace(t.name,(select name from T1 where T1.id=t.id),(select name from T2 where T2.id = t.id));
update table2 t set t.name=replace(t.name,(select name from T2 where T2.id=t.id),(select name from T1 where T1.id = t.id));
```

But,it is not giving correct result.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in a single pass, as you are overwriting the values you want to move in the next step.  Here's a solution using a temporary table:

```
SELECT * INTO #temp FROM table1;
UPDATE t1 SET name = t2.name FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id;
UPDATE t2 SET name = t1.name FROM #temp t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id;
DROP TABLE #temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

A little modification in your query and it worked.

create table temp1 as select * from table1;

update table1 set name = (select name from table2 where table2.id = table1.id);

update table2 set name = (select name from temp1 where temp1.id = table2.id);

Thanks,
Vinita Singh

Comment: I see the problem, you tagged your question as SQL Server, but it obviously is Oracle or some other RDBMS, as that syntax doesn't work for SQL Server.  Which explains why my answer didn't work for you, as I gave you a SQL Server script.